# cakephp timezone warning notice on debug enabling

Tags: php, cakephp, timezone

In CakePHP-1.2, When i put `debug` on to `1 or 2` it gives me below timezone related warnings/notices.

Warning (2): date() [http://php.net/function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Calcutta' for 'IST/5.0/no DST' instead [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1149]

Any idea, how can i remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you php.ini find

```
date.timezone
```

if it's commented, remove comment and set it to your timezone.

For example: date.timezone = Europe/London

Comment: You can also just set it in config/core.php using the function mentioned by @dogmatic69

Answer (score 3):

like the error says, set the timezone properly, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php